# Openshift pod continuously restart with message "Crash loop back off" for my node js application

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have deployed the following simple code as an openshift application but it crashes and restarts continuously

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_adress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/name/:name', function(req, res){
  res.render('profile', {name: req.params.name});
});

app.listen(server_port, server_ip_adress, function(){
  console.log("Listening on " + server_ip_adress + ", on port " +             server_port);
});
```

The following message is displayed in the openshift log 
[Log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgSZ8.png)

As I am new to Openshift and Node.js cant figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Are you using the S2I builder for NodeJS supplied? Details for that are at https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/blob/master/6/README.md so perhaps compare how your application code is structured to requirements there. Also compare to the same app at https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/tree/master/6/test/test-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, it looks like you need to configure your start task in package.json. Here is a sample package.json with the start script:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
     "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```